# Добавить кнопку "Купить"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Создал шаблон для страницы (лендинг), где есть кнопка купить (Woocommerce). В админке есть всего один товар. Нужно привязать эту кнопку к товару, чтобы при нажатии на нее - происходил переход в корзину, где можно продолжить оформление заказа именно этого товара (наверное по id как то). Как это сделать, подскажите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode('[recent_products per_page=1" columns="1" orderby="date" order="desc]');
?>
```

Этот шорткод выведет весь товар(если он у вас один, то один и выведет), что у вас есть и там будет и цена, и Купить с переходом в корзину и ссылка на товар. А дальше дело за Css

Comment: Спасибо, полезно! Но мне нужно немного другое. У меня свой php шаблон для главной страницы и на этой странице есть кнопка купить. Нужно чтобы эта кнопка была привязана к этому конкретному товару, как то так.

Comment: Товар потом будет добавляться?

Comment: Нет, сайт для одного товара, лендинг. После нажатия на кнопку - переход в корзину.

Comment: Пусть кнопка  является ссылкой на страницу Корзина, а там по умолчанию всегда есть этот товар.  <a class="cart-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>">
 Купить
</a> Это код на корзину, можно как и тот код вывести в любом месте твоего шаблона.

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда сделать, чтобы в корзине всегда был этот товар?)

Comment: как вариант, при входе на страницу Корзина, вы получаете урл товара и отмечаете его как в корзине для покупки.

Comment: еще вариант, при нажатии Купить сработает функция положить товар в Корзину и потом редирект на страницу.

Comment: вот я не понимаю, как выбрать именно этот товар. есть какой то живой пример из этих двух?

Comment: Перенаправить в корзину после успешного добавления; включите в настройках в Админке и потом, выведите кнопку добавить в корзину, потом добавить этот код function.php add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_product_link' );
function custom_product_link( $link ) {
global $product;
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( $product->get_permalink( $product->id )).'" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button">Подробнее</a>';
}

Comment: [add_to_cart id="82" sku=""]
[product id="82" sku=""] а это вариант шорткода на корзину с определенным товаром. Вариантов множество

Comment: Спасибо! Помог очень, не удаляйте комменты только :)

Comment: Не за что, удачи в работе)!